# ngRoute not working: [$compile:tpload]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Im new to angularjs so its hard for me to figure this thing out. Im getting error of [$compile:tpload]. What could be a problem here?
HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-view>
    ...
</div>
<a href="#main">Access</a>
```

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ["ngRoute"]);
App.config (function ($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
 .when("/main", {
     templateUrl : "yup.html"
 })
});
```

yup.HTML:

```
<p>...</p>
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: did you downloaded and included the `angular-route.js` file?

Comment: The `templateUrl` is a relative path from the file you declare the routing.  The error is indicating that it cannot load the template so make sure your pointing to the html file correctly.

Comment: It is in the same folder as other ones, so it should point correctly and yes I included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no issue with your code, except that the `angular-route.js` file is not loading. **Change the source link from `http` to `https` to get it working**. Browser is blocking the url as script through `http` is insecure. **[Updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1g32hz7GPOujbjWr5Dwp?p=preview)**

Comment: It is in the same location

Comment: Can you template as I've done above and check if it's working ?

Comment: Now it doesnt show any errors and there is and empty space for it but it doesnt show up when i added: <script type="text/ng-template" id="yup.html">

  </script>

Comment: You might've missed adding content in it. Can you check that once.

Comment: You mean add <p>Content of the template.</p>? If so then it only shows Content of the template.

Comment: Yeah. That is the purpose of  your routing right? What is your requirement exactly? Can you create a plunkr and share?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/37ayj0bCdOvdgivWKZiy?p=preview I mean the problem is that I need to write what i need betwean the lines of script that way when i need to get it from yup.html

Comment: @Vanagasa: I've updated your plunkr, removed the `ng-template`, there was an error loading angular-route, fixed it. https://plnkr.co/edit/1g32hz7GPOujbjWr5Dwp?p=preview. Check and let me know if that is working as expected.

Comment: It works as expected, but somehow if i copy all this to my code it doesnt work and i would like to know how you fixed it

Comment: The issue in the plunkr was that `angular-route` file was not loading, I've changed the source url to `https` from `http`

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)